# HttpClient with CFNetworkHandler and NTLM

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using the new HttpClient class in MonoTouch and I would like to use the CFNetworkHandler instead of relying on the .NET stack. As explained in Miguel's post here: http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2013/Jun-07.html it's much better to rely on CFNetwork. It wont consume Mono threads, it will wake up 3g/WiFi from idle mode...

But there is one gotcha: there is no way, out of the box, to use this handler and get NTLM authentication. Whereas with the .NET stack it's standard.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Instead of `CFNetworkHandler` you might want to check out ModernHttpClient (https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) - maybe it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

CFNetworkHandler unfortunately does not implement the Credentials property.

You can however use ModernHttpClient (which i believe is even better - no evidence for this).

ModernHttpClient does not implement NTLM "out of the box", however it does override the function "DidReceiveChallenge".
All you need to do, is check whether the challenge is NTLM, and pass the Credentials to the completionHandler